# Cannot make the button wider by Java Code

Tags: java, android

I don't know what is the problem. I am creating the simple phone-book, so i have name of abonent, image and call button under the name. And when i try to set width with the `layoutParams` parameter for button, it doesn't change anything, `btn.setWidth();` doesn't work either.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams sublparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams childparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
        linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
            LinearLayout sublinear = new LinearLayout(this);
            Button btn = new Button(this);
            ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
            TextView txt = new TextView(this);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
            txt.setText("Abonent " + (i+1));
            btn.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.mygreen));
            btn.setText("+3800000");
            txt.setLayoutParams(childparams);
            btn.setLayoutParams(imageparams);
            img.setLayoutParams(imageparams);
            linear.addView(txt);
            sublinear.addView(img);
            sublinear.addView(btn);
            linear.addView(sublinear, sublparams);
        }
    }
}
```

[result of programm, green vertical lines are buttons, that i cannot to make wider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvGsQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

your button is using `LayoutParams` to set width and heigth so you need to change this properties here (`LinearLayout.LayoutParams(widht, height`)):

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 300);
```

and the size of your button must change, because you are setting this values.

```
 btn.setLayoutParams(imageparams);
```

Comment: Thank s, but i ve done that before, unfortunately it`s not working(